# How to reference a static class from dll at runtime

Tags: c#, xslt, dll, xsltc

I'm using `xsltc.exe` create `A.dll` from `A.xslt`.
Then refenrence `A.dll` in my project and do the transform:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(typeof(A)); // A is a public static class from A.dll
xslt.Transform(RootPath + "A.xml", RootPath + "A.txt");
```

but how can I refenrece `A.dll` at runtime and do the transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to both generate and reference the DLL all at run time. The good news is that you can load an assembly at run time using `Assembly.LoadFrom`.

The below is taken from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=netframework-4.7.2) and the technique is called Reflection.

```
Assembly SampleAssembly;
SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\\A.dll");
// Obtain a reference to a method known to exist in assembly.
var aTypes = SampleAssembly.GetTypes();
MethodInfo Method = aTypes[0].GetMethod("Method1");
// Obtain a reference to the parameters collection of the MethodInfo instance.
ParameterInfo[] Params = Method.GetParameters();
// Display information about method parameters.
// Param = sParam1
//   Type = System.String
//   Position = 0
//   Optional=False
foreach (ParameterInfo Param in Params)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Param=" + Param.Name.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("  Type=" + Param.ParameterType.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("  Position=" + Param.Position.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("  Optional=" + Param.IsOptional.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I just want my class `A` from dll, your code have `Method1` which I don't know what should I replace since there is no method in class  `A`. And thank you, I forgot to mention I want to generate and reference the DLL all at run time

Comment: I update the code a little - put a breakpoint on var aTypes = SampleAssembly.GetTypes();
MethodInfo Method = aTypes[0].GetMethod("Method1"); and use the watch feature in Visual Studio to inspect the aTypes object. This will list your classes. aTypes[0] is just referring to the first class in the assembly.